# Gparted doesn't detect any partitions

Tags: ubuntu, installation, partitioning, ubuntu-10.04, gparted

I am trying to install Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on my laptop. First I installed it inside Windows and when it boots for first time I got the error message "couldn't find root filesystem , try partition table to fix the problem " . When I want to install it on a single partition (normally) and when it told me to chose a partition I don't find any partition (entire disk) .

I have 2 primary partitions and 3 logical partitions. How can I proceed with the install ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your partition table is probably bad. **DO NOT write a new partition table or you will wipe out your hard drive!**

The solution is repairing it. You can first try using testdisk and rewriting it, if it doesn't work you can use

> fdisk -l

To check for problems on your hard drive.

For more information, see

> man fdisk

Comment: thanks martin , but how to rewrite it without wipe my hard drive ?

Comment: Check the manpages for fdisk.

One thing more, remember to not do that **inside** the hard drive - use another hard drive, or a live-enviroment in a C or USB drive.

Comment: Before you mess with fdisk you should consider to backup your old (broken) partition table, just in case fdisk does more harm than good.

Comment: but how to backup old partition table