# ubuntu : partition table error (Partition table entries are not in disk order)

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-10.04, partitioning

i have asked about [Gparted doesn’t detect any partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/139641/gparted-doesnt-detect-any-partitions) and  i tried the command :

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and the result is (after partition info ) :

```
Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

so how to fix this problem , please help me .
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if any partitions take up partial blocks (those will have a `+` in the values) then this won't work.

Record the partition values, delete the partitions that are out of order, recreate them in proper order, then change anything like the grub config or `/etc/fstab` that may list the partitions by number instead of label.